# Swift - Google Firebase Authentication with Email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to run the example of Google Firebase Authentication with Email. As I tried the email example of https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/authentication/AuthenticationExampleSwift/EmailViewController.swift I get errors in the project.

My Code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let email = self.userEmailTextField.text, let password = self.userPasswordTextField.text {
        showSpinner({
            // [START headless_email_auth]
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                self.hideSpinner({
                    if let error = error {
                        self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
                })
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
            // [END headless_email_auth]
        })
    } else {
        self.showMessagePrompt("email/password can't be empty")
    }
}
```

I get an error on `showSpinner({...})` and at the very end on `self.showMessagePrompt("email/password can't be empty")`:

[image]

However, the error from the very end `showMessagePrompt` does not appear on `self.showMessagePrompt` few lines before. Maybe it has to do with my Swift Version, I tried to convert to 3, but my complete project was broken after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in that quickstart-ios, they uses bridging-header of `UIViewController+Alerts.h`  file which is not implemented by you and not added by you in your project.

So one solution is to use `UIViewController+Alerts.h` as bridging header in your view controller or remove/modify your code something like this code..

```
 @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let email = self.userEmailTextField.text, let password = self.userPasswordTextField.text {
        // [START headless_email_auth]
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            // [START_EXCLUDE]

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                //show alert
                return
            }
            self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
        // [END headless_email_auth]
    } else {
       print("email/password can't be empty")
       //show alert
    }
 }
```

You can find `UIViewController+Alerts.h` and `UIViewController+Alerts.m` files [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/authentication/AuthenticationExample)

Comment: I see the problem, but I don't see any headers included in the example file. So where do I have to include them?

Comment: its included in example too https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/authentication/AuthenticationExampleSwift  in this file check https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/authentication/AuthenticationExampleSwift/BridgingHeader.h

Comment: is there some sort of swift component that can you can include without having to use a header file? How can you replicate the spinner using everything in the object library?